# Vertical scrolling news modules for Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, scroller

How can I get a free vertical scrolling news modules for Joomla 1.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Xpert Scroller](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/15315). This will fulfill your requirement.